# Pointer to .text in real mode assembly

Tags: assembly, mingw, i386, real-mode

There must be something fundamental I'm misunderstanding about real mode addressing. I am trying to set up a function to print text via BIOS interrupt in real mode. I am testing the code using a .com file executed under DOSBox. The .text section ends up at 0x1000 (0x0F00 in the .com file). So lets say I want to print the first letter of that text.

```
xor ebx, ebx
mov ecx, 1
mov ah, 10
mov al, ds:[0x1000]
int 0x10
```

That works, and prints out 'H', because I have no imagination. But then I don't want it to just print out the same letter. I want to pass in a pointer, and I want to increment that pointer as I'm printing out more text. At this stage, I'm happy enough just reading offset from the register. So I make the following change.

```
mov edx, 0x1000
mov al, ds:[edx]
```

And no character gets printed. I've tried using esi and edi registers, same result. Using lea edx, byte ptr [0x1000] produces same result. Worse, trying to use 16 bit equivalents (dx, si, di) results in program hanging up. I've tried looking through the machine code int he .com file, and I can't find anything obviously wrong.

I am compiling the code with gcc using a custom linker script and an objcopy call to make a .com file. No libraries are linked, and target architecture is 386.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: Full listing.

directio.s

```
.intel_syntax
.global _printChar

_printChar:
    push ebp;
    mov ebp, esp;

    xor edx, edx;
    xor ebx, ebx;
    xor eax, eax;
    mov ecx, 1;

    mov ah, 10;
    mov edx, 0x1000;
    mov al, ds:[edx];
    int 0x10;

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp;
    ret;
```

dirTest.c

```
asm
(
    ".code16gcc;\n" \
    "call _dosmain;\n" \
    "mov ah, 0x4C;\n" \
    "int 0x21;\n"
);

#include "directio.h"

int dosmain(void)
{
    printChar("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

com_mingw.ld

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x0100;
    .text :
    {
        *(.text);
    }
    .data :
    {
        *(.data);
        *(.bss);
        *(.rodata);
    }
    _heap = ALIGN(4);
}
```

All of this compiles with the following command line.

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -Os -nostdlib -m32 -masm=intel -march=i386 -ffreestanding -o dirTest.com -Wl,--nmagic,--script=com_mingw.ld dirTest.c directio.s
```

Followed by

```
objcopy dirTest.com -O binary
```

Comment: Out of curiousity at the beginning of your code did you setup the `DS` (data segment) with something like `mov ax, @data` followed by `mov ds, ax`? It would help if we saw your entire program if it wasn't overly long. oh I see you are using GCC so setting up `DS` will be a bit different. I'd also like to see your linker script and the actual commands you use to build and link

Comment: I have added the full listing. Currently, I am testing everything in DOS environment. So DOS sets up cs and ds to the offset where it loads the .com file. These appear to be set up correctly, since loading character from ds:[0x1000] works. Code begins at 0x100. .text ends up at 0x1000.

Comment: Just to make sure this isn't some weird limit on offsets from segment, I have tried the following:
mov edx, cs
add edx, 0x0100
mov ds, edx
xor edx, edx

Again, cod works fine with mov al, ds:[0], but fails miserably with mov al, ds:[edx]. And I can't tell why these aren't the same thing.

Comment: Yeah sorry, getting late, didn't notice it was a COM program at first (so yes, CS=DS=ES)

Comment: Something that is confusing. You pass the string on the stack using the call to printChar. Any particular reason you don't use the address passed on the stack rather than hardcoding 0x1000?

Comment: In a 16 bit  .com file is DS=CS, so it make no sense to setup DS with the same segment address again. And to use the DS-segment overrride prefix is also senseless. user5408560 can use: **"mov si,0x100 mov cx,1 mov ah,0xA  P1: mov al,[si] cmp al,0 jz Exit int 0x10 inc si jmp P1. ExIt:"** if the string is terminated with a zero byte. But it is also possible to set the CX-register with the count of the string without to use a loop.

Comment: @DirkWolfgangGlomp : see my followup comment about CS=DS=ES

Comment: The goal is to eventually copy the passed-in pointer, e.g. mov edx, ss:[ebp+8]. I am using hard-coded address for testing only. The results are exactly the same regardless of how I set the edx register. mov al, ds:[edx] ends up setting al to 0. Same with any other register I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_printChar` should be a 16-bit function, so don't assemble it as 32-bit. Add a `.code16gcc` to the top of the .s-file and change 32-bit registers to 16-bit:

```
.code16gcc
.intel_syntax
.global _printChar

_printChar:
    push bp;
    mov bp, sp

    xor dx, dx
    xor bx, bx
    xor ax, ax
    mov cx, 1

    mov ah, 10
    mov dx, 0x1000
    mov al, ds:[dx]     ; ERROR! See comments.
    int 0x10

    mov sp, bp
    pop bp
    ret
```

Now, it should (hopefully) work.

Comment: Compiler complained about ds:[dx], but replacing it with ds:[si] fixes it, which is probably more in line with how I'm using the registers anyways. So I'm assuming this has something to do with segment registers being used differently in 32 and 16 bit modes? Or is it simply the case that I should switch to real mode before starting to throw 32 bit code around?

Comment: @user5408560: Oh yes, sorry. There is no base register option `[dx]`, only `[edx]`. Your solution (change to `[si]`) is  the best.

Answer (score -1):

It must be about three decades since I last wrote any real mode code, in `.com` image format, but here are a few observations:

- It is unusual to define multiple sections, when writing `.com` format code. The format permits only one *segment*, with a maximum initial image size of 64Kb; conventionally, this may comprise *logical* sections, often called "CODE" and "DATA", or "TEXT" and "DATA", but they *must* be grouped into a single *physical* segment; any explicit segment, of the "STACK" class, is prohibited.
- MS-DOS is a 16-bit operating system, so you must write code using *only* the 16-bit registers, (or their 8-bit sub-registers).
- The 16-bit processors did not allow you to use any registers, other than BX, SI, DI, and BP, as base registers for indirect memory addressing; you *cannot* use DX, (as you do), CX, or AX for this purpose; (you likely *can* use SP, but you normally leave that alone, reserving it for its intended use as the stack pointer).
- When the operating system loads a `.com` format process image, it first allocates an environment block, then the program segment following it. The first 256 bytes of the program segment is then filled in with administrative data, (creating what is commonly referred to as the Program Segment Prefix, or PSP), and the `.com` image is loaded immediately thereafter, starting at address 0x100, (the 0x1000, to which you allude, is just an arbitrary offset within the program segment, at which (presumably) your data is defined, but there is nothing sacrosanct about it -- program code could just as easily appear there.
- Once the image has been loaded, the operating system sets all four segment registers to the start of the program segment, and sets CS:IP (by performing a FAR JMP, or possibly a FAR CALL), to begin execution of your process at the appropriate entry address, which is *always* at offset 0x100 (*not* related *in any way* to your 0x1000 data address) within the program segment.

Comment: It seems to have more to do with mode than OS, but yeah, 32 bit instructions were the culprit. And yes, the 0x1000 offset is arbitrary. Just where .text ended up in this particular .com file. The actual offset I'll want to use will be passed on the stack as function parameter. The rest is in line with the assumptions I've been working with, but it's useful to have the confirmation. Thank you.

Comment: So, factual accuracy attracts down votes? Kind of confirms my overall impression of the general worthlessness of SO; guess I will not be bothering to offer any further advice, or corrections of the _misinformation_ which proliferates.

Comment: @KeithMarshall, I have upvoted you. I learnt a lot from your answer. This is the advantage of SO. Believe me more people will come to appreciate your effort/knowledge.